# Cannot import project name.items from P2Item

Tags: python, import, python-3.11

I have a problem with import my project items from items file
I have a virtualenv host
project name example p2
when i use this code
`from p2.items import P2Item`

i have this error :

`Import "p2.items" could not be resolved`

i use p2.p2 but not work
checked p2 project direction

I am in Windows 10 OS

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please give us as many details as possible. The file structure of your project would be helpful in this particular question.

Comment: project direct : Scripts\p2\p2\spiders

Comment: project items direct : \Scripts\p2\p2

Comment: Use the tree command and edit your original post to include the full file tree (https://superuser.com/questions/372509/how-to-get-tree-of-folders-in-cmd)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.